# Detect another touch while one finger is still on the screen

Tags: ios, ios5, cocos2d-iphone

I want to detect a touch while one finger is still on the screen means that still touch canceled for that is not called... is it possible because i want to ignore that touch and perform operation on the next finger......

Thanks

Comment: In touchesBegan:withEvent: and touchesEnded:withEvent: methods, first parameter (touches) has newly touched or released fingers, and [event touchesForView:self] (where event is the second parameter) returns all fingers (old fingers and newly touched or released fingers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

//those are all touches on this began call
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {

        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
        CGPoint convertedLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

//those are ALL the touches on screen
 NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
```

You can also keep track of touches by reading the hash code of the touch and saving it using `int firstTouchHash = [touch hash]`.

You can check in the TouchesBegan if the touches set and the `allTouches` set have the same `count` (in this case we are touching the screen for the first time), in that case we can save the hash `int firstTouchHash = [touch hash]`

When we touch the screen again, the `allTouches` contains more elements than `touches` and we always know wich was the first touch because we have the hash saved.
(without saving the hash, if we touch with 1 finger, then with a second one and then with a third, when the third touch occurs we dont know which of the 2 previous touches is the first, because they both are in the `allTouches` set (and a set is an unordered collection of elemenents) )

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure multiple touch is enabled on the view, either through the `multipleTouchEnabled` property or the Multiple Touch checkbox in the storyboard editor.